# Wait for forEach with a promise inside to finish

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with waiting for my forEach loop, which has a promise inside, to finish. I can't find any real solution, that would make the script wait till the end, before continuing with the execution. I cannot make the someFunction synchronous.

```
makeTree: function (arr) {
    arr.forEach(function (resource) {
        someModule.someFunction(resource).then(function () { //a Promise
            //do something with the resource that has been modified with someFunction
        });
    });
    // do something after the loop finishes
}
```

Comment: are you using angularjs?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Instead of `forEach()` use `map()` to create an array of promises and then use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
let promiseArr = arr.map(function (resource) {
    // return the promise to array
    return someModule.someFunction(resource).then(function (res) { //a Promise
        //do something with the resource that has been modified with someFunction
        return res;
    })
});

Promise.all(promiseArr).then(function(resultsArray){
   // do something after the loop finishes
}).catch(function(err){
   // do something when any of the promises in array are rejected
})
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, I had the same doubt and I didn't want to do with packages or something complex. this is the best response for these cases, very simple and brilliant. again, thanks. regards

Comment: Simple and clear to read + maintain: thank you for this solution!

Comment: not working for me if I don't have anything return from my function

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
makeTree: function (arr) {
   var promises = [];
   arr.forEach(function(resource) {
      promises.push(someModule.someFunction(resource));
   });
   Promise.all(promises).then(function(responses) {
      // responses will come as array of them
      // do something after everything finishes
   }).catch(function(reason) {
      // catch all the errors
      console.log(reason);
   });
}
```

You can refer this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) for more on `Promise.all` with simple examples.