# Executing promises in array with Promise.all breaks them

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

I have an array of userIds that I use in getOrdersByUserId() to get the orders placed by these users for a specific month:

```
function getOrdersByUserId(userId, month = 4) {
    const apiService = new ApiService();

    return apiService.getOrdersList(`?OrderingUser=${userId}`)
        .then(orders => {
            const monthOrders = orders.filter(order => new Date(order.FromTime)
            .getMonth() === month);

            return monthOrders;
        });
}
```

Here's getOrdersList() in ApiService:

```
getOrdersList(queryString = '') {
    return httpsRequest.createRequest(this.URL.ordersList + queryString, {}, this.requestHeaders, 'GET')
        .then(result => JSON.parse(result).Records);
}
```

httpsRequest.createRequest returns a promise that resolves with the response from the API (I can share that code too if necessary).

When I test getOrdersByUserId() with 8 userIds I have, I get the correct records every time. Where this breaks is when I put these calls into a promise chain and execute them with Promise.All(). I wrote the below code with help from this answer: [Wait for forEach with a promise inside to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45082038/wait-for-foreach-with-a-promise-inside-to-finish)

```
const promises = userIds.map(userId => {
            return getOrdersByUserId(userId, month)
                .then(orders => {
                    return orders;
                });
        });

        Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
            console.log(results);
        }).catch(err => {
           console.log(err);
        });
```

Testing with the 8 userIds I get this error four or five times:

```
(node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

After a lot of console logging it seems that this error occurs when httpsRequest.createRequest() gives a result that is an empty string, instead of a JSON response from the API. So why would all of these calls with the same userIds work individually, but break when executed in a promise chain? How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a common misunderstanding: You don't *execute* promises. `Promise.all` doesn't "run" anything. A promise is just a means of watching an operation to know when it's done and whether it worked or failed.

In your case, the operations are started by `apiService.getOrdersList`, as soon as you call it.

What you're seeing suggests that

1. The API service doesn't like you sending it eight simultaneous requests (perhaps it rate-limits), and
2. The promise from the API service resolves with a value that isn't valid JSON rather than rejecting when it can't handle #1 (which is unfortunate, it should reject, not resolve).

Nothing about using `Promise.all` breaks these operations. But apparently, running eight of these operations in parallel breaks.

You could run them in series (one after another):

```
userIds.reduce((p, userId, index) => {
    return p.then(results => {
        return getOrdersByUserId(userId, month)
         .then(orders => {
             results[index] = orders;
             return results;
         });
    });
}, Promise.resolve([]))
.then(results => {
    // `results` is an array of results, in the same order as `userIds`
})
.catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
});
```

Each call to `getOrdersByUserId` waits for the previous one to complete; the final result is an array of results in the same order as the `userIds` array.

Comment: Thanks so much for the thoughtful reply! However I get an error running this, "ReferenceError: p is not defined". Do you know what's causing this?

Comment: @no_parachute44 - Sorry, that was a typo. It should be `acc.p = acc.p.then...`.

Comment: Ok now I'm getting "userIds.reduce(...).then is not a function" as well as five of the errors first noted in my question.

Comment: @no_parachute44 - Sorry, mis-remembered the pattern. Fixed above (one hopes).

Comment: TJ, you are a God among men! Thank you so, so much, I can't tell you how much this helps me. Hope you have a great day :)

Comment: @no_parachute44 - LOL! A God amongst men wouldn't have got it wrong twice first. :-) I'm really glad that helped!

Comment: One last question, how do I get that last results variable out of the function? getOrdersByUserId().then(result => console.log(result)); logs "undefined" @T.J. Crowder

Comment: @no_parachute44 - Your `getOrdersByUserId` function returns a promise of the value it gets from `Records` on the parsed JSON. If you're getting `undefined`, that property's value is `undefined` or the property doesn't exist.

Comment: Below where your comment "// `results` is an array of results," is, I return results. If I console log it there it shows the correct information. Is that not the place to do it? How should I be returning results then?

Comment: @no_parachute44 - If all of this is in a function, then: 1. Add `return` just before `userIds.reduce`, 2. Remove the `catch` handler, that's the caller's job, and 3. Remove the `then` handler that has only that comment in it, the caller will get results when it consumes the promise.