# Firestore Javascript nested foreach queries looping before the second query

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to get the document ID for places and and review that is referenced on one of the subcollection on my 'users' collection. After getting it i perform another query to then use those IDs to get the actual value of the review field which is in another collection 'places'

```
    var query = db.collection('users/ziRsQGzbuwVp805SYY9vkZIbbJ93/myRecommendations');
        query.get().then(function(querySnapshot){
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc){
            locData.placeID = doc.data().placesDocument;
            locData.reviewID = doc.data().reviewDocument;
            var query2 = db.collection('places').doc(locData.placeID).collection('reviews').doc(locData.reviewID)
            query2.get().then(function(doc){
                locData.review = doc.data().specRemarks         
                locdataArr.push(parse)
                console.log(locdataArr)
```

however, the foreach from the first query

```
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc){
            locData.placeID = doc.data().placesDocument;
            locData.reviewID = doc.data().reviewDocument;
            var query2 = db.collection('places').doc(locData.placeID).collection('reviews').doc(locData.reviewID)
            query2.get().then(function(doc){
                locData.review = doc.data().specRemarks
```

seems to loop before doing the second query which leads to only the last output from the first query going through the second with these output from the log

[image]

the review was successful (one value is actually null in the firestore and the other was TEsting/n)
but the recorded IDs were only from the last output of the first query. How should i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

What you're observing is what I would expect.  Since `get()` is asynchronous and returns a promise, it will always return immediately, before the results of the query are available.  If you put a bunch of calls to `get()` in a loop, the loop will always complete before any of the results of the async work is complete.

If you want to wait until a bunch of promises are resolved, you should collect them into an array and use `Promise.all()` to create another promise that resolves when all of them are complete.

See also:

- [How to use promise in forEach loop of array to populate an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38362231/how-to-use-promise-in-foreach-loop-of-array-to-populate-an-object/38362312)
- [Wait for forEach with a promise inside to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45082038/wait-for-foreach-with-a-promise-inside-to-finish)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I now understand the concept of promises but i can't seem to wrap my head as to how am i supposed to apply it on my current code. Do you mind if you could give hints as to what i should do

Comment: The other questions I linked to have specific examples.