# Modify external object in promise function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of objects (books) that are missing some fields, so I'm using `node-isbn` module to fetch the missing data. However, I'm having trouble persisting the updates to the objects. Here's some example code:

```js
const isbn = require('node-isbn');

var books = []; // assume this is filled in elsewhere

books.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item.publication_year == '' ||
        item.num_pages == '') {
        isbn.provider(['openlibrary', 'google'])
            .resolve(item.isbn)
            .then(function (book) {
                item.num_pages = book.pageCount;
                item.publication_year = book.publishedDate.replace( /^\D+/g, '');
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log('Book not found', err);
            });
    }
    console.log(item)
});
```

However, the console log shows that the `num_pages` and `publication_year` fields are still empty. How can I fix this?

Comment: Seems correct.. only you're logging console before async return

Answer (score 1):

Try not to use Promise inside forEach

Comment: What's the right way to update the items inside the array then?

Comment: You can map each of them into array of promises then use Promiss.all to execute it

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45082038/wait-for-foreach-with-a-promise-inside-to-finish

Answer (score 1):

Put your console.log inside the then block , it will print the result for you.You are doing a asynchronous operation by resolving promise so it will take some time for the data to come back , however since your console.log is outside of that promise , that will get executed first.

So if you want to see those values, you should put your console.log inside your then block.

However, You can use `await` and `for of` syntax to achieve the result

```
for await (item of books) {

  if (item.publication_year == '' || item.num_pages == '') {
         const book = await isbn.provider(['openlibrary', 'google'])
            .resolve(item.isbn);

         item.num_pages = book.pageCount;
         item.publication_year = book.publishedDate.replace( /^\D+/g,'');

    }
    console.log(item)
}

console.log(books)
```

Comment: Sure, I can do that. The end goal though, is to use the modified array of items (save to disk, etc), so how can I do that after the loop ends?

Comment: Seems like my version of node doesn't like the "await" keyword. I get "SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word". Using version 14.3.0.