# RowDataPacket returns empty object but it is not empty [React/Next]

Tags: mysql, reactjs, api, next.js

I've been stressing around trying to fix this and I've burnt myself out. I'm calling my serverless mysql trying to get kanbans from teams. I've used this method multiple times and all were working fine but that is most likely because of they only return single item whilst this returns multiple items.

This is my code which returns empty object.

```js
async function getKanbans(team_id){
    let kanbans = [];
    await sql_query(`SELECT id, sName FROM table WHERE iTeam = ?`, [team_id])
    .then(result => {
        result.forEach(kanban => {
            // console.log(kanban);
            kanbans.push({
                id: kanban.id,
                name: kanban.sName
            });
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });

    console.log(kanbans);
    return kanbans;
}
```

As you can see.. I am trying to print kanbans and I do get:

```json
[
  { id: 1, name: 'Kanban_1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Kanban_2' }
]
```

of out it. Then I'm trying to return it to the item that called this function and this is how that looks like:

```js
teams.push({
   id : team.id,
   sName : team.sName,
   sColor : team.sColor,
   aKanbans : result[0]['selectedTeam'] == team.id ? getKanbans(team.id) : null,
});
```

(a small snippet of something bigger)

Okay, so now when I try and look at the data response (from the frontend) I get this:

```json
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "Found teams",
  "teams": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "sName": "Team1",
      "sColor": "#fcba03",
      "aKanbans": {}
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "sName": "Team2",
      "sColor": "#2200ff",
      "aKanbans": null
    }
  ]
}
```

aKanbans from Team1 is empty, empty object. What the **** do I do? I tried mapping it and still got an empty object. React/javascript is not my main language, I just like to learn. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where are you calling `teams.push(...)`? Could you provide the full code of the function where it's used? Also, `getKanbans` is an async function, so you need to `await` for it, i.e. `result[0]['selectedTeam'] == team.id ? await getKanbans(team.id) : null`.

Comment: @juliomalves Sure, here ya go https://pastebin.com/TA7g0nRb

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wait for forEach with a promise inside to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45082038/wait-for-foreach-with-a-promise-inside-to-finish)

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `async / await` function with normal Promises handling.

Try to change your `getKanbans` code like this:

```
async function getKanbans(team_id) {
  let kanbans = [];
  try {
    const result = await sql_query(
      `SELECT id, sName FROM table WHERE iTeam = ?`,
      [team_id]
    );
    result.forEach((kanban) => {
      kanbans.push({
        id: kanban.id,
        name: kanban.sName,
      });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  return kanbans;
}
```

And then populate the teams using (declare the parent `async`):

```
teams.push({
    id : team.id,
    sName : team.sName,
    sColor : team.sColor,
    aKanbans : result[0]['selectedTeam'] == team.id ? getKanbans(team.id) : null,
 });
```

Comment: I created a pastebin with the changes you told me to do:
https://pastebin.com/TA7g0nRb

New error: 
Error: error: await isn't allowed in non-async function
  
aKanbans : result[0]['selectedTeam'] == team.id ? --> await <-- getKanbans(team.id) : null,


Any ideas?

Comment: Try to remove the `await` before the `getKanbans` function call

Comment: It still returns aKanbans: Object {} 
 :(